# How do I add an app-specific (i.e. Trello) URL to my home screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, default-applications, bookmarks, url, trello

I've got an app-specific URL that opens in a particular app, rather than my webbrowser.

In this case Trello, for example someone sends me a link to a Trello card, like `https://trello.com/c/xyz123abc/Some-Random-Card` in an email or text message. When I click that, it opens in Trello.

Now I want to add this as a **shortcut in my Android home screen**. How do I do that, or how do I get that to **open in the intended app** (in this case Trello) rather than my browser?

What I tried was visiting the URL in my browser (which shows a web view of the particular trello card) and add that as a bookmark to the home screen. But when I click that bookmark, it opens in my browser again, it doesn't recognize the URL as being intended for Trello, as is the case when clicking that same link in an email or messaging app.

Comment: Your app must implement this in it's manifest and register itself for a specific action to take when a user open a specific link. So you should ask the app developers​ for this.

Comment: @esQmo_ Thanks, but this seems to be the case already, because if I click those links in an email or messaging app, it correctly opens in Trello instead of Chrome. I'm really looking for a way to create such shortcuts or bookmarks on my home screen. I think because I explicitly created this home screen shortcut from Chrome, it is somehow linked to Chrome or set to open in Chrome. So maybe if there is a generic way to just set up a URL as a home screen shortcut (not adding it from Chrome)? I guess that might do the trick.